# web scrape using simple html DOM parser

Tags: web-scraping, html-parser

How to extract specific details like name and price of a product from Amazon platform using simple html DOM parser. for example: **(product-image, name and price)**.

Comment: the question is actually too wide.. you didn't talk about what kind of scraper you are going to use.. and lots of details on how to get to the product page. It's very hard to focus on one problem alone here. Maybe if you showed a single actual product page, it was possible to tell you strategies on how to parse those single informations in terms of css selector for example. But you are asking much more there. When you say DOM parser you mean running js code in that page? or do you mean a whole standalone app having a dom parser to scrape amazon web pages?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $httpClient->get('https://www.floridaleagueofcities.com/research-resources/municipal-directory/');
$htmlString = (string) $response->getBody();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$titles = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="accordion-body"]//ul//li/a');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).